# Confusion regarding stage2 and stage2final in PTW.scala

Tags: rocket-chip

What do stage2 and stage2final signals mean in PTW.scala?

Does stage2 mean the second translation stage (GPA --> HPA)? I also feel confused about aux_count signal, which only plus 1 when stage2_pte_cache_hit?

I think stage2 should be false in the first translation (GVA ---> GPA), and then be true in the second translation.